# SQL: compare one value with whole column if the value available anywhere in the same column. give a name to every value comes between those 2 values

Tags: sql, mysql

| created_date | rake_device | rounded_geo_lat | rounded_geo_lng | idle_or_moving | new_idle_moving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08-01-2024 11:27 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 10:27 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 09:27 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 08:27 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 07:27 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 06:27 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | moving | idle |
| 08-01-2024 05:27 | a-b | 28.28 | 76.39 | moving | idle |
| 08-01-2024 05:21 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 05:12 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 04:12 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 03:12 | a-b | 28.29 | 76.39 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 02:12 | a-b | 28.24 | 76.39 | moving | moving |
| 08-01-2024 03:13 | a-b | 28.24 | 76.39 | moving | moving |
| 08-01-2024 03:09 | a-b | 28.245 | 76.33129 | moving | moving |
| 08-01-2024 05:12 | a-b | 28.324 | 76.3921 | idle | idle |
| 08-01-2024 05:12 | a-b | 28.324 | 76.3921 | idle | idle |

Based on the above data, I want to derive new column `new_idle_moving`. The logic for this column would be: I

I have to assess every pair value of `rounded_geo_lat,rounded_geo_lng`. If the same pair to be found anywhere between that partition (rake_device, created_date desc) then all values coming between them should be mark as `idle` and moving it should be as it is.

Note: we just have to replace those moving tags as idle if previous and after lat, lng for that moving tag is the same.  AND DATA IS IN THE INCREMENTAL FORMAT SO EVERY NEW HOUR NEW ENTRY WILL BE GENERATED SO WE HAVE TO COMPARE THAT TO THE ENTIRE COLUMN OF LAT LNG.

I tried the following query, but it converts all values as idle which is wrong output.

```
  WITH GroupedData AS (
  SELECT
    created_date,
    rake_device,
    rounded_geo_lat,
    rounded_geo_lng,
    idle_or_moving,
    MAX(idle_or_moving) OVER (PARTITION BY rake_device, grp ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS max_idle_or_moving
  FROM (
    SELECT
      created_date,
      rake_device,
      rounded_geo_lat,
      rounded_geo_lng,
      idle_or_moving,
      SUM(change_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY rake_device ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS grp
    FROM (
      SELECT
        created_date,
        rake_device,
        rounded_geo_lat,
        rounded_geo_lng,
        idle_or_moving,
        CASE WHEN LAG(rounded_geo_lat) OVER (PARTITION BY rake_device ORDER BY created_date DESC) = rounded_geo_lat
               AND LAG(rounded_geo_lng) OVER (PARTITION BY rake_device ORDER BY created_date DESC) = rounded_geo_lng
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS change_flag
      FROM YourTable
    ) AS ChangeFlag
  ) AS GrpAssign
)
SELECT
  gd.created_date,
  gd.rake_device,
  gd.rounded_geo_lat,
  gd.rounded_geo_lng,
  gd.idle_or_moving,
  CASE WHEN gd.max_idle_or_moving = 'idle' THEN 'idle' ELSE gd.idle_or_moving END AS new_idle_moving
FROM GroupedData gd
ORDER BY gd.created_date DESC;
```

here is db fiddle link :https://dbfiddle.uk/w5pNGy5B
[image]

Comment: Provide **source** table and data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired final data state as a table. Add explanations to each final line (column .. is set to .. because ..). See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @Akina provided in the question. can u solve this question? or you just here to contribute on beautification part of question?

Comment: Well. Imagine that there exists 4 (consecutive) points. Their `(time, lat, lon)` are (schematically) `(1,1,1)`, `(2,2,1)`, `(3,1,1)`, `(4,2,1)`. None other points contains these `(lat, lon)` values. What are desired idle values for each of these points? Does all 4 values must be `idle`?

Comment: Look: The rows with `created_date` values `2024-08-01 02:12:00` and `2024-08-01 03:13:00` have absolutely the same lat/lon values. But you want to mark 3 of 4 lines between these timepoints as `moving` - why?

Comment: @Akina why ? that is my use case. i explained question my question very well. if u think u can not provide an answer please focus on beautification for other questions. and it is moving because previous timestamp of that is diff. i suggest u focus on this timesamp and values. `08-01-2024 07:27`
`08-01-2024 06:27`
`08-01-2024 05:27`
`08-01-2024 05:21`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you because I don't understand your task completely. You think that you explain it "very well" - that's your opinion. You'd wait for somebody who will understand you.

Comment: The published data isn't in datetime order so what order is it in? and there are 3 entries for 5:12 so how should these be treated in the sequence of events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** answer after clarification in comment

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    data_new (CREATED_DATE, RAKE_DEVICE, ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ROUNDED_GEO_LNG, IDLE_OR_MOVING) AS
        ( Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 11:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 10:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 09:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 08:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 07:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 06:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.28, 76.39, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:21:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 04:12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 03:12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 02:12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.24, 76.39, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 03:13:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.24, 76.39, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 03:09:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.245, 76.33129, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.324, 76.3921, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-b', 28.324, 76.3921, 'idle' From Dual  Union All
  --
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 11:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 10:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 09:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 08:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 07:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 06:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:27:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.28, 76.39, 'moving' From Dual Union All
          Select STR_TO_DATE('2024-08-01 05:21:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 'a-c', 28.29, 76.39, 'idle' From Dual 
        ),
```

... create cte (grid) that will define date start and date end for all the rows having the same LAT and LNG values. Use that values to define row numbers for the rows with same start/end dates and count rows with same start/end dates...

```sql
  grid AS
        ( SELECT    a.CREATED_DATE, a.RAKE_DEVICE, a.ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, a.ROUNDED_GEO_LNG, a.IDLE_OR_MOVING,
                    ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By a.RAKE_DEVICE, a.DATE_START, a.DATE_END Order By a.RAKE_DEVICE, a.CREATED_DATE Desc) "RN",
                    COUNT(a.CREATED_DATE) Over(Partition By a.RAKE_DEVICE, a.DATE_START, a.DATE_END) "CNT",
                    a.DATE_START, a.DATE_END
         FROM     ( Select CREATED_DATE, RAKE_DEVICE, ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ROUNDED_GEO_LNG, IDLE_OR_MOVING,
                           Min(CREATED_DATE) Over(Partition By RAKE_DEVICE, Concat(ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ' - ', ROUNDED_GEO_LNG)) "DATE_START", 
                           Max(CREATED_DATE) Over(Partition By RAKE_DEVICE, Concat(ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ' - ', ROUNDED_GEO_LNG)) "DATE_END"
                    From      data_new
                    Order By  CREATED_DATE Desc, ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ROUNDED_GEO_LNG
                  ) a
       )
```

... now you can mark new idle or moving depending on first/between/last row of the same group....

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select CREATED_DATE, RAKE_DEVICE, ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ROUNDED_GEO_LNG, IDLE_OR_MOVING,
       Case When RN = 1 And CNT = 1 Then 'moving'
            When CNT = RN Then 'moving'
       Else 'idle'
       End "NEW_IDLE_MOVING"
From   grid
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
CREATED_DATE        RAKE_DEVICE ROUNDED_GEO_LAT ROUNDED_GEO_LNG  IDLE_OR_MOVING NEW_IDLE_MOVING
------------------- ----------- --------------- ---------------- -------------  --------------------
2024-08-01 03:13:00 a-b                 28.240          76.39000    moving      idle
2024-08-01 02:12:00 a-b                 28.240          76.39000    moving      moving
2024-08-01 03:09:00 a-b                 28.245          76.33129    moving      moving
2024-08-01 11:27:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 10:27:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 09:27:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 08:27:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 07:27:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 06:27:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    moving      idle
2024-08-01 05:21:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 05:12:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 04:12:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 03:12:00 a-b                 28.290          76.39000    idle        moving
2024-08-01 05:12:00 a-b                 28.324          76.39210    idle        idle
2024-08-01 05:12:00 a-b                 28.324          76.39210    idle        moving
2024-08-01 05:27:00 a-b                 28.280          76.39000    moving      moving          
--
2024-08-01 11:27:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 10:27:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 09:27:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 08:27:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 07:27:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    idle        idle
2024-08-01 06:27:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    moving      idle
2024-08-01 05:21:00 a-c                 28.290          76.39000    idle        moving
2024-08-01 05:27:00 a-c                 28.280          76.39000    moving      moving      */
```

Comment: no it is not working not giving me the exact answer. here is the requirnment : look at the current lat lng and compare the same with whole column if  you find anywhere same then lable all rows ((which comes between that row and duplicate of that row)) including first row as 'idle' and last row for that window as 'moving'

Comment: @vish Just posted updated answer....

Comment: so there is whole dataset and more then 70 rake_device u did calculation for only 1 however, i if i wanna do the same for all, can u update the answer? we can partition it by rake_device but would greate if u can update answer

Comment: @vish Just add rake_device as first (before a.DATE_START) in partition by  of ROW_NUMBER() And in partition By of COUNT() . Add the same to partition by in Min() And Max() before Concat(). That should be enough. They all are in cte grid.

Comment: @vish ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By a.RAKE_DEVICE, a.DATE_START, a.DATE_END Order By a.CREATED_DATE Desc) "RN", and COUNT(a.CREATED_DATE) Over(Partition By a.RAKE_DEVICE, a.DATE_START, a.DATE_END) "CNT", and Min(CREATED_DATE) Over(Partition By RAKE_DEVICE, Concat(ROUNDED_GEO_LAT, ' - ', ROUNDED_GEO_LNG)) "DATE_START", and same with Max() DATE_END...

Comment: it is not giving correct answer it is 70% correct tho. so look at the image, a column is your result and b column is result we want.

Comment: @vish Try it now, Added RAKE_DEVICE to Order By too of ROW_NUMBER() in grid

Comment: @vish Just posted additional sample data and additional resultset...

Comment: have u made any changes in code?

Comment: @vish order by in rownumber....

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select *
  ,case 
    when (select max(created_date) from data_new d2
          where d2.rake_device=d1.rake_device and d2.created_date<d1.created_date
           and d2.rounded_geo_lat=d1.rounded_geo_lat
           and d2.rounded_geo_lng=d1.rounded_geo_lng
         ) is not null
       then 'idle1'
     when rounded_geo_lat=lag(rounded_geo_lat,1,-1)
                        over(partition by rake_device order by created_date)
         and rounded_geo_lng=lag(rounded_geo_lng,1,-1)
                  over(partition by rake_device order by created_date)
       then 'idle2'
    else 'moving'
    end new_idle_moving
  ,(select max(created_date) from data_new d2
    where d2.rake_device=d1.rake_device and d2.created_date<d1.created_date
         and d2.rounded_geo_lat=d1.rounded_geo_lat
         and d2.rounded_geo_lng=d1.rounded_geo_lng
     )  prev
from data_new d1
```

With your test data output is

| created_date | r._device | r._geo_lat | r._geo_lng | idle_or_mo... | new... | prev(pos date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-08-01 02:12:00 | a-b | 28.240000 | 76.390000 | moving | moving | null |
| 2024-08-01 03:09:00 | a-b | 28.245000 | 76.331290 | moving | moving | null |
| 2024-08-01 03:12:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | moving | null |
| 2024-08-01 03:13:00 | a-b | 28.240000 | 76.390000 | moving | idle1 | 2024-08-01 02:12:00 |
| 2024-08-01 04:12:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 03:12:00 |
| 2024-08-01 05:12:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 04:12:00 |
| 2024-08-01 05:12:00 | a-b | 28.324000 | 76.392100 | idle | moving | null |
| 2024-08-01 05:12:00 | a-b | 28.324000 | 76.392100 | idle | idle2 | null |
| 2024-08-01 05:21:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 05:12:00 |
| 2024-08-01 05:27:00 | a-b | 28.280000 | 76.390000 | moving | moving | null |
| 2024-08-01 06:27:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | moving | idle1 | 2024-08-01 05:21:00 |
| 2024-08-01 07:27:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 06:27:00 |
| 2024-08-01 08:27:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 07:27:00 |
| 2024-08-01 09:27:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 08:27:00 |
| 2024-08-01 10:27:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 09:27:00 |
| 2024-08-01 11:27:00 | a-b | 28.290000 | 76.390000 | idle | idle1 | 2024-08-01 10:27:00 |

Comment: no it is not working not giving me the exact answer. here is the requirnment : look at the current lat lng and compare the same with whole column if you find anywhere same then lable all rows (which comes between that row and duplicate of that row) including first row as 'idle' and last row for that window as 'moving' –